# Need to turn on project twice in order for screen to work!

Tags: i2c, attiny, display, lipo

This problem is really stumping me. I made a simple printed circuit board with an ATtiny85, a 128x64 I2C OLED display, and a Sharp IR analog distance sensor. You can view the circuit here: [circuits.io](https://circuits.io/circuits/3184178-attiny85-counter-with-oled-screen-rev-2#pcb).

If I turn the system on using the simple 3-pin slide switch that I put on the board, the screen does not turn on. I can see that the system is powered though, because I can see a little bit of red light escaping from the IR sensor where some of the IR light borders on the visible end of the spectrum. If I turn the board off then immediately turn it back on, the display powers up just fine. If I upload a new program to the board and use the programmer's 3.3v power I don't need to do it twice - the screen works first time.

I'm using a 3.7v LiPo battery, so I know power is not an issue (everything is 3-5v tolerant, and the LiPo battery can deliver plenty of current). Why do I need to turn it on twice in order for the screen to work? Thanks!

Comment: Add a delay at the start of your program before you initialise the display. It sounds like the display is taking a moment to charge its capacitors and become ready.

Comment: @Majenko Awesome, thanks. A 100ms delay before starting the screen solved it nicely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a 100ms delay before calling `oled.init(0x3c); oled.clear(); oled.startScreen();` made this problem go away.